# Send an email to the address on the 10th column of the selected row when a button is clicked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to programme a "Send Email" button such that when I select a row and click the button, the system will retrieve the email address from column J of that row and send a fixed message to that email address.

However, I encounter the error "Invalid email: Undefined", which probably mean my code to retrieve the cell is incorrect.

Where did I go wrong?

This is the code for the button.

```
    function sendEmail() {
  // define a couple constants for the function
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // if valid, get the correct row of data.
    var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();

  // get the range for that row
    var rowRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).getValues();

    // Make sure the selected row has text
  if(sheet.getRange(row,9).isBlank()) {
    ui.alert("Please assign a teacher for this AOR.");
    return;
  }

  // Build the object to use in MailApp
    var address = rowRange[0][10];
    var AORno = rowRange[0][4];
    var body = "Dear Teacher, Your AOR number " + AORno + "has been approved. You may now proceed with claiming your expenses under this AOR."
    var msg = "Email has been sent to " + address + "."
    var subj = "[Automatic notification] Your AOR has been approved."

  // Send the email
    ui.alert(msg, ui.ButtonSet.OK)
    MailApp.sendEmail(address, subj, body);

    // set the send status in col 4
    sheet.getRange(row, 11).setValue("Sent");
}
```

The link of the spreadsheet is [here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aWMjCoxljZrhuDsV4ryFmQfrHFOBGSjraId-sDrT8Ak/edit?usp=sharing)

Please refer to the AOR tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your script and shared spreadsheet, I thought that there may be the problem at the index of array. The index of range for spreadsheet starts from 1. But that of array starts 0. So how about modifying as follows?

#### From :

```
var address = rowRange[0][10];
var AORno = rowRange[0][4];
```

#### To :

```
var address = rowRange[0][9];
var AORno = rowRange[0][3];
```

If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: @Phi Yen Nguyen Thank you for your response.